# nginx rewrite rule for each sitemap.xml in language subdirectory

Tags: nginx, sitemap, nginx-location, hugo

I have a sitemap index which prints out the url to each sitemap for each langauge e.g:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
     <loc>https://example.com/en/sitemap.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
     <loc>https://example.com/ga/sitemap.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
     <loc>https://example.com/sl/sitemap.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

for which I have written a location block as follows:

```
     location ~ ^/(sitemap.xml) {
        root /var/www/html;
     }
```

which works perfectly fine for the sitemap index, now the sitemap for each language is in subdirectory named with the same language code. I have tried different rewrite rules, how can be the rule written such that the primary sitemap and the sitemap in subdirectory is also viewable.

Comment: Try: `location ~ /sitemap.xml$ {`

Comment: @RichardSmith   thank you. tried it but the langauge specific urls redirects to index itself.

Comment: There must be another `location` which is taking precedence.